# how to add two separate actions for an item in a galleryview of android?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am trying to implement two actions  for each item in a gallery.
I tried having onitemclick and onitemlongclick, but it doesnt seem to work. 
Any suggestions in this regard?

Comment: You may try to use dragging. User drags item to the left => one action; to the rigth => another action.

Comment: Please post some code snippets that show what you tried, and describe what exactly doesn't work. Otherwise we can just guess around.

Comment: Here's the code http://pastebin.com/gkLB6P0p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to impliment contextmenu with 2 items:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {       
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Select action");       
            menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Action1");
            menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Action2");

            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }
```

and set onClickListener

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                 openContextMenu(imageView);
            }

        });
```